# Get PWA connection string - projectserver2013

Tags: project-server

Is there any way to get the connectionstring of pwa site in projectserver2013. It works well in projectserver2010, but not in 2013.

I used the following article in 2010 http://bastion-integrator.com/2011/04/how-get-%D1%81onnection-string-project-server-2010-for-pwa-instance/

I have changed the dll version in 2013 but still, no use. in the Type.GetType('') method It returns NULL in 2013.

I actually trying to get Project UID of the current site from SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, in the current site itself the value is available .

currentWeb.AllProperties["MSPWAPROJUID"]

it returned the proj UID and worked in both 2010 and 2013. If there is any other solution please share here.